# Special Roman/Japanese Encoding with RStudio Sweave

Tags: sweave, rstudio, japanese

Is there a way for having multiple enconding support in RStudio Sweave?

I have the following citation, and using different encodings like uft8 or cjk just results in errors.

**Reference**

> METI. (2014c). Shōenerugī nikansuru jōsei oyobi torikumi no jōkyō nitsuite 省エネルギーに関する情勢及び取組の状況について. Ministry of Economy, Trade and Industry - Japan. Retrieved from http://www.meti.go.jp/committee/sougouenergy/shoene_shinene/sho_ene/pdf/002_03_00.pdf

**Bibtex**

```
@techreport{meti_shoenerugi_2014,
    title = {Shōenerugī nikansuru jōsei oyobi torikumi no jōkyō nitsuite 省エネルギーに関する情勢及び取組の状況について},
    url = {http://www.meti.go.jp/committee/sougouenergy/shoene_shinene/sho_ene/pdf/002_03_00.pdf},
    language = {Japanese},
    urldate = {2015-05-05},
    institution = {Ministry of Economy, Trade and Industry - Japan},
    author = {{METI}},
    month = jun,
    year = {2014}
}
```

Your help is highly appreciated
Thank you